# Can snow golems exist in Savanah?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, pc

I am in a savannah biome and have been working on starting a village. Recently, I tried to build snow golems for defenders. Once they are built, they immediately start to take damage and die soon after. I have read the Minecraft wiki and found the, short, list of biomes that snow golems can't survive. Given the list and information also posted in the biomes page of the wiki, I'm thinking that the article needs to be amended to say that snow golems can't exist in temperatures of 0.95 or greater. Can anybody confirm or simply clear up my confusion?

## Links

- [Snow Golems](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Snow_golem)
- [Biomes](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Biome)

Answer (score 3):

As it is stated in the link you provided ([Biomes](http://minecraft.fandom.com/wiki/Biome)) the Savannah biome has a heat rating >= 1.0. Which means that Snow golems won't survive.

On a further note, I believe rain also hurts them, so perhaps covering them is also a good idea in biomes where they can survive.